# Homeomorphism between plane with different topologies

Tags: general-topology

How would you show that spaces $(\mathbb{R^2},\cal{T}_r)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2,\cal{T}_b)$, where $\cal{T}_r$ is a topology generated by jungle river metric ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662616/help-sketching-jungle-river-metric-in-mathbbr2)) and equivalently $\cal{T}_b$ is generated by the British Rail metric ([3.15 second one](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/Top.pdf)), are not homeomorphic?

I tried to think of any elementary topological property, with which I can characterize only one of those spaces, but they seem to be so alike... Yet not homeomorphic. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the railway system, there exists a (unique) point such that its complement is the disjoint union of infinitely many connected open sets.

No such points exists in the jungle. In short: The "main stream" is like $\mathbb R$ with standard metric, hence has at most two connected components after removing a point. But the corresponding open sets must reach into each of the vertical "arms", which look like $\mathbb R$ as well. 
To see this more explicitly: For any point $(x_0,y_0)$ the subsets $\{\,(x,y)\mid x<x_0\,\}$, $\{\,(x,y)\mid x>x_0\,\}$, $\{\,(x_0,y)\mid y<y_0\,\}$,  $\{\,(x_0,y)\mid y>y_0\,\}$ are even *path* connected (along the obvious polyline paths that the metric suggests), hence $\mathbb R\setminus\{(x_0,y_0)\}$ has at most four connected components.

Comment: Isn't the British rail metric the one in which an open set is an open interval on a line crossing $(0,0)$ point? Maybe I used the wrong name. If not, singletons are not open.

Comment: Huh, apparently there are more than one rail metric. The one I'm used to is where two points are the usual Eucliden distance apart when they are linearly dependent, and $\|x\|+\|y\|$ otherwise. Definition 3.15 in [these notes](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/Top.pdf) gives both.

Comment: Yeah, I meant the second one. Does you argument still hold?

Comment: Hm, I used the one in WP you linked to. Back to the drawing-board ... (to bed, actually)

Answer (score 3):

Removing the origin from the river metric gives us 4 path-components (the positive $y$-axis, the negative $y$-axis, and the sets $\{(x,y): x > 0\}$ and $\{(x,y): x < 0\}$.

If we remove a point from the railway metric, then either we get uncountably many path components (if we remove the origin), or 2 (for all other points).