# Difference between subspace and subset in topology

Tags: general-topology

In Murkres's book Topology, I read that Y(a subset of some set X）is called the subspace of X if we consider the subspace topology. But what is the difference here between being a subspace and a subset?
[the definition in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV04z.png)

Comment: There is no real difference in this context. The term "subspace" typically means a subset with some additional structure, e.g. topology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could ask the same question about topological spaces as a whole: What is the difference between a set and a topological space? The answer there is quite clear: A topological space is a set together with a topology on that set.

Your question has a quite similar but more *specific* answer: a subspace of a topological space $X$ is a subset $Y \subset X$ together with a *specific* topology on $Y$, namely the subspace topology.

Answer (score 1):

### Part1

This has been sorta asked recently [for vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574418/what-is-the-definition-of-a-subspace). (Lee Mosher answered there too.) The analogy I'd like to use here is **subgroup vs subset group**:

You can make a group $G$ of the set $[0,2\pi)$ and some operation (I forgot the specifics, but I believe it's described in this [elementary introduction of adding angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group#Elementary_introduction)) s.t. $G$ is isomorphic to the [circle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group). $G$ then is not a subgroup of $\mathbb R$. But since $G$'s set $[0,2\pi)$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ and since both $G$ and $\mathbb R$ are groups, I like to think of $G$ as a '**group subset**' of $\mathbb R$: The sets can be made into groups with 1 a subset of the other, but the subset group's structure is not inherited from the superset group's structure.

### Part2

Going back to topology:

Just pick any non-standard topology $\mathscr T$ you want for $\mathbb R$ to make $(\mathbb R,\mathscr T)$. Then for standard topology $\mathscr S$ on $\mathbb R$, we have that $(\mathbb R,\mathscr T)$ and $(\mathbb R,\mathscr S)$ are **subsets (or topological subsets or whatever)** of each other but they are not necessarily topological subspaces of each other.

### Part3

Notice that the definition in the book for subspace topology says that *with this topology*. If you have $X$ and $Y$ as just sets, then...

1. $\mathscr T$ is a topology on $X$ and then $\mathscr T_Y$ is a topology on $Y$.
2. Then $(Y, \mathscr T_Y)$ and $(X,\mathscr T)$ are topological spaces.
3. Then $(Y, \mathscr T_Y)$ is then defined as a *topological subspace* of $(X,\mathscr T)$ in the sense that $Y$ is a subset of $X$ and that the topology $\mathscr T_Y$ on $Y$ is *inherited* from the topology $\mathscr T$ on $X$.

You can come up with a different topology $\mathscr A$ on $Y$. In this case $(Y, \mathscr A)$ is not (necessarily) a topological subspace of $(X,\mathscr T)$.

### Part4

The point of this topology for subsets into becoming subspaces is like...

If we're talking about say continuity of some map $f:(X,\mathscr T) \to (Z,\mathscr B)$ and then we later restrict the map $f|_Y:(Y,\text{what topology?}) \to (Z,\mathscr B)$ to say $f|_Y$ is 'still continuous', then for this to be sensible we must have  the topological structure on $Y$ for the map $f|_Y$ is $\mathscr T_Y$.

### Part5

Also just now I saw this related question: [What does it mean to equip a subset with the subspace topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032670/what-does-it-mean-to-equip-a-subset-with-the-subspace-topology)